# Tesseract fail/error when compiling (nameoffset)

Tags: python, tesseract

im having an error message after using `make` on tesseract

params.cpp:43:23: error: ‘`nameoffset`’ was not declared in this scope
   if (!fp.Open(file + nameoffset, nullptr)) {

Comment: DO NOT use development version unless you are able to fix such problem (it is fixed in master already).

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it by editing the src/ccutil/params.cpp
what i did is revert the code https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/commit/96025c79231913a8fdbb2e7f41c15432e237858a#diff-6ef249dd4294cae3dea58c8dbc4db1cf

add this on line 32

```
#define PLUS          '+'        //flag states
#define MINUS         '-'
```

and this line 45

```
int16_t nameoffset;              // offset for real name

  if (*file == PLUS) {
    nameoffset = 1;
  } else if (*file == MINUS) {
    nameoffset = 1;
  } else {
    nameoffset = 0;
  }
```